# Read unicode file in php

Tags: php, unicode, decode, encode

How to read Unicode file in php.

I have used file_get_contents() function, but after reading file content, I am getting content in decode format(not readable format)

Please provide me your suggestions.

Thanks

-Pravin

Comment: Thinking about this, I think it's more likely that this is a header problem (not setting the proper [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) header for the encoding).  But the thing is, without code, I don't want to take a wild stab in the dark about what possibly is the problem...

Comment: Just a comment. I used utf8_decode($yourStringHere); to decode unicode to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [iconv](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to transform your unicode string to any other encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this unicode decode/encode, try running the content you got from `file_get_contents` through

- [`utf8_encode`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8
- [`utf8_decode`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) — Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1

If your file content is not ISO-8859-1, consider [Elzo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077766/read-unicode-file-in-php/4077816#4077816) to use `iconv`.